# make android app force 'in-app purchase' after some use

Tags: android

I want to make my application disable after some use, to force users activate the application using 'in-app purchase'. I dont want to use the internet and web services and I need my app to continue usage calculation of app, even after 'clear data' or reinstall...

Is there any way to do this ? Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Clearing data or reinstalling truly removes all data related with your application. You'd have to use something online-based.

Comment: I know that, but is there any good way to save usage data on memory in a file for example? I prefer offline way much more... :)

Comment: You could possibly write to file and store it somewhere. Then if they remove/reinstall it, it checks it. But then, all the the user has to do is find that file and remove it. Offline approaches to this are always bad, though. Only ever use a server to check this kind of thing.

Comment: If you're intent on sticking with offline for now. Here's an example of how to use/write to files: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: ok man, i think limiting users in options of the application, and asking them to use 'in-app purchase' to remove the limitations is really better, so !! as i respected to hear... THANK YOU. :)